# Pinax app.css not found

Tags: css, django, pinax

I am using pinax template for the first time.I am following the documentation.
I started the project.Did everything mentioned [here](http://pinaxproject.com/pinax/quick_start/).
The problem is the page is displayed but the css and javascript files are not loaded.
The browser console gives error saying

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) app.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) site.js
```

Am i missing something here? Is there anything else to do which is not there in documentation?

Comment: It seems the documentation you are looking at is not updated. Either the created settings.py file is not pointing to the static folder or the starter project is not creating the necessary files and folders. I used to use the starter project before without a problem but today I downloaded the most up-to-date version of the pinax-cli and I quickly encountered the same problem as you. I recommend you to contact the developers directly via pinax.slack.com

Comment: Ok...Thank you....!

Comment: Have you tried my new answer, @MOHAMMED NUMAN? I got it directly from the Pinax Slack community and it worked for me!

Comment: Yup it did work.Thank you for the solution Solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Make sure you have node installed before proceeding.

**New procedure for installing a Pinax project  (working as of January 3rd, 2018):**

```
# First, activate your virtualenv or similar
. ~/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/activate
# Second, install Pinax command line tool
pip install pinax-cli
# Install Pinax project
pinax start  {project type} {custom name}
cd {custom name}
# Install your project's dependencies from 'package.json' into node_modules/
npm install 
# Install Django/Pinax dependencies
pip install -r requirements.txt
# Prepare for Django
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py loaddata sites
python manage.py createsuperuser
# Run a proxy on port 3000  
npm run dev #  this will run webpack with watch and compile code as it changes
# Browse to http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

*Note: The README.md file inside the project should provide you with the right installation instructions.*